# Bitnami Odoo Addons over Init Container not work

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, odoo-14

I use the Helm Chart from Bitnami https://bitnami.com/stack/odoo/helm for the Odoo installation.
The chart works without problems. But what I do not manage is that I can download addons using git and an init container.
I have tried the following.

My init Container

```
initContainers:
  - name: git-hr-attendance
    image: bitnami/odoo
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"
    args: ['apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install git && git clone https://github.com/OCA/hr-attendance /bitnami/odoo']
    volumeMounts:
      - name: odoo-data
        mountPath: /bitnami/odoo
        #subPath: addons
```

Output Logs

```
fatal: destination path '/bitnami/odoo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

What I also tried is to load the git repo into the /tmp folder but this has another effect the data is not copied from the `/tmp` folder to the `/bitnami/odoo/addons` folder.
But the folder `/bitnami/odoo` will be displayed in `/tmp.`

After that I adjusted the init container.

init container

```
initContainers:
  - name: git-hr-attendance
    image: bitnami/odoo
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"
    args: ['apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install git && git clone https://github.com/OCA/hr-attendance /bitnami/odoo/addons']
    volumeMounts:
      - name: odoo-data
        mountPath: /bitnami/odoo
        subPath: addons
```

Output Logs

```
Cloning into '/bitnami/odoo/addons'...
```

The data is now copied but after that the config file is no longer available.

```
odoo 11:45:27.24 

odoo 11:45:27.24 Welcome to the Bitnami odoo container

odoo 11:45:27.24 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-odoo

odoo 11:45:27.24 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-odoo/issues

odoo 11:45:27.24 

odoo 11:45:27.26 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_* env vars

odoo 11:45:27.32 INFO  ==> Restoring persisted Odoo installation

odoo 11:45:27.36 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to the database server

grep: /opt/bitnami/odoo/conf/odoo.conf: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have an idea or experience with Odoo what to do about this. So that I can download my addons via git per init container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is related to the way the Odoo image verifies if it should initialize the app or instead restore an old installation at the [setup](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-odoo/blob/0f15d63b1d56f403e54a6f74c4993015c5cb5969/14/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/odoo/setup.sh#L26-L27) stage. If it finds that the `/bitnami/odoo/` directory is not empty it will do the latter ([link](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-odoo/blob/0f15d63b1d56f403e54a6f74c4993015c5cb5969/14/debian-10/prebuildfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/libpersistence.sh#L114-L122)), and so the

```
grep: /opt/bitnami/odoo/conf/odoo.conf: No such file or directory
```

is displayed because it tries to find files that should have being created from a previous installation (there are symlinks between some folders in `/opt/bitnami/odoo` and `/bitnami/odoo`).

You can modify the image [at this point](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-odoo/blob/0f15d63b1d56f403e54a6f74c4993015c5cb5969/14/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/odoo/run.sh#L20) to add your custom logic.

Comment: Thank you very much !
I will do it this way. 
But what is not clear yet, because of the updates must be built for each update of the addons a new image?

Why is described in the helmet chart that you can use an Init Contianer?

Comment: You mean the "copy addons from git and push to /bitnami/odoo/addons" right? I agree it is badly worded and incomplete. IMO what they wanted to say is "Use the initContainer to get the addons and then copy to /bitnami/odoo/addons". I think you can do the following: git clone to a folder (e.g. tmp) with the initContainer and then the logic in the image could be just "copy addons downloaded in tmp to /bitnami/odoo/addons"

Answer (score 0):

I found another method to solve this problem without recreating the image.
I mount the volume and check if the addons directory exists. then I clone the repo.
This prevents the directory from being created at the first start. Of course, the pod must be deleted after the first start.

```
initContainers:
  - name: init-clone-repo
    image: alpine/git
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: ["[ -d /git/addons ] && /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/OCA/hr-attendance /git/addons/git; exit 0"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: odoo-data
        mountPath: /git
```